# Find minimum 'pair' in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sorting

I have an array of 'array pairs':

```
[[time, distance], [time, distance], [time, distance], [time, distance], ...]
```

I want to find the index of the 'pair' with the minimum time, and if there are multiple 'pairs' with the same minimum time, take the pair with the minimum distance.

e.g. if I have:

```
[[5, 5], [1,7], [2,6], [1,6]]
```

I want to return 3. (i.e. the index of the 4th element).

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array#sort` does exactly what you want.

```
myarray = [[5, 5], [1,7], [2,6], [1,6]]
myarray.sort
#=> [[1, 6], [1, 7], [2, 6], [5, 5]]
```

So, we just need to find the element in the original array matching the first element in the sorted array.

```
ndx = myarray.index myarray.sort[0]
#=> 3
```

EDIT: I originally used the spaceship operator, but realized it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Ruby on Rails, but I wrote a little PHP code to achieve your goal. I hope you can extract the idea from it.

```
<?php

$timesAndDistances = [['t' => t1, 'd' => d1], ['t' => t2, 'd' => d2], ..., ['t' => tn, 'd' => dn]];

$lowestTime_withDistance = [['t' => null, 'd' => null, 'i' => null]];

foreach($timesAndDistances as $index => $timeAndDistance)
{
    $time = $timeAndDistance['t'];
    $distance = $timeAndDistance['d'];

    if($lowestTime_withDistance[0]['t'] == null)
    {
        $lowestTime_withDistance[0] = ['t' => $time, 'd' => $distance, 'i' => $index];
    }
    else 
    {
        if($lowestTime_withDistance[0]['t'] > $time){
            $lowestTime_withDistance[0] = ['t' => $time, 'd' => $distance, 'i' => $index];
        }
        elseif ($lowestTime_withDistance[0]['t'] == $time)
        {
            $lowestTime_withDistance[] = ['t' => $time, 'd' => $distance, 'i' => $index];
        }
    }
}

if(count($lowestTime_withDistance) == 1)
{
    echo 'Index of element with minimum time is ' . $lowestTime_withDistance[0]['i'];
}
elseif(count($lowestTime_withDistance) > 1){
    $lowestDistance = [['d' => null, 'i' =>null]];

    foreach($lowestTime_withDistance as $timeWithDistance)
    {
        if($lowestDistance[0]['d'] == null)
        {
            $lowestDistance[0] = ['d' => $timeWithDistance['d'], 'i' => $timeWithDistance['i']];
        }
        else
        {
            if($lowestDistance[0]['d'] > $timeWithDistance['d'])
            {
                $lowestDistance[0] = ['d' => $timeWithDistance['d'], 'i' => $timeWithDistance['i']];
            }
            elseif ($lowestDistance[0]['d'] == $timeWithDistance['d'])
            {
                $lowestDistance[] = ['d' => $timeWithDistance['d'], 'i' => $timeWithDistance['i']];
            }
        }
    }

    if(count($lowestDistance) == 1)
    {
        echo 'Index of element with minimum time and distance is ' . $lowestDistance[0]['i'];
    }
    elseif (count($lowestDistance) > 1)
    {
        foreach($lowestDistance as $aLowestDistance)
        {
            echo 'Index of an element with minimum time and distance is ' . $aLowestDistance['i'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing quick code to achieve this:

1. Say Array a has following elements

   > [[5, 5], [1,7], [2,6], [1,6]]
2. Create a copy of array in b:

   > b = a
   >
   > b= [[5, 5], [1,7], [2,6], [1,6]]
3. Sort b

   > b= b.sort
   >
   > b = [[1, 6], [1, 7], [2, 6], [5, 5]]
4. Iterate over a nested loop

   > smallest = b[0]
   >
   > index = 0
   >
   > a.each do |iter_orig| unless a.nil?
   >
   > if iter_orig.eql?smallest
   >
   > break;
   >
   > end
   >
   > index++;
   >
   > end
   >
   > end
   >
   > puts "Index for smallest Time/Distance - " + index